# Is this shower channel gap part of the design, or poorly sealed?

Tags: plumbing

Originally purchased a home and didn't catch this during inspection. The shower stall seems to have pieces that aren't filled with grout.

Not sure if it's always been this way.

Is this by design?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well done, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like things moved after initial installation. You can see where there was sealant (probably caulking, one would not use grout to seal a seam like that) there at one time. Probably someone removed the old sealant after a gap/crack appeared, but never came back to finish the job by applying new sealant.

Whether or not there was a leak caused by this condition... only you would know.

> ...what's the best method of filling it up?

Use a flexible bath/shower caulking like silicone.

Comment: I've seen comments state that caulk in a channel-by-design would actually contribute to mold, as the channel gives a vent for water to dry. Do you think this applies to my situation?

Comment: I don't think that is a designed drainage gap (opinion); I think it was designed to give a little bit of flexibility (like up to 1/4") during installation. It might perhaps also serve to allow some small amount of expansion/contraction/movement during use, without panels buckling/cracking; I don't think a flexible caulk seal would defeat that. If it were in my home I would seal it completely, including at the top.

Comment: Probably a good idea to leave a gap in the caulking at the very bottom, just in case, so any trapped water can drain. (I think this is still true even if the gap is unintended.)